# Apify - Dataset Not In Same Order As URL List

Tags: jquery, url, dataset, apify

I have tried relentlessly to solve this issue, but have run out of ideas. Why does Apify give me a dataset that is never in the same order of the URL requestList?

```
{ url: 'https://www.ecstuning.com/Search/SiteSearch/63210301815 '},
{ url: 'https://www.ecstuning.com/Search/SiteSearch/63216935865 '},
{ url: 'https://www.ecstuning.com/Search/SiteSearch/63216935866 '},
{ url: 'https://www.ecstuning.com/Search/SiteSearch/63216935863 '},
{ url: 'https://www.ecstuning.com/Search/SiteSearch/63216935864 '},
{ url: 'https://www.ecstuning.com/Search/SiteSearch/63217160907 '},
{ url: 'https://www.ecstuning.com/Search/SiteSearch/63217160935 '},
```

The dataset returned is upside down, and the lines are out of sequence. This makes it impossible to paste back into a spreadsheet we are building. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Apify scrapes are running requests concurrently so the later URL can finish earlier than the first one. If this is really important for you, you can add maxConcurrency: 1 to scrape one by one. Or push data to temporary array and then push that array into dataset at once.